# Overwriting files when installing laravel Breeze

Tags: laravel, breeze

I installed the Breeze starter kit in an existing Laravel project and it no longer works.
I put back the route which had disappeared in web.php but when launching my page, an error indicates that the controller is not found even though it does exist.
Was a file other than web.php modified during Breeze installation?
Thank you for your answers.

I added the route that had disappeared in web.php

Comment: There are multiple files that are updated/added possibly removed when installing the breeze starter kit from routes to controllers to blade files. If you are using git, just undo the changed files using `git checkout -- .` (Will undo **all** changed files, not staged files)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.